# Laravel - How do i insert text into trix editor

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, trix

I was wondering how could I introduce text from my database trix field back into the editor for further editing. Thank you in advanced !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say you have a model `$trixText` and there is a field `text`. So you can populate with this. You can set the content by putting in the value attribute.

```php
<form …>
  <input id="x" value="{{ $trix->text }}" type="hidden" name="text">
  <trix-editor input="x"></trix-editor>
</form>
```

Comment: @CristianCutitei ok so you posted two questions. can we solve one by one?